# Opening csv files from my hard drive and importing into a database

Tags: python, database

I'm trying to import data from a csv file saved on my hard drive into a database that I created. However when I go to run the code to iterate through the file and add to the database, I get the following error:

NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Users/ajb56/Documents/Programming/CGS_sales_database.csv'

The file will open using the designated path, but i'm unsure why python is saying it is invalid.

Here is the code snippet where I define the directory and attempt to use the file in the for loop.  The error I get is on the on the line with the for loop.

```py
localFilePath = "C:/Users/ajb56/Documents/Programming/CGS_sales_database.csv"

for file in os.listdir(localFilePath):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        insertRows(localFilePath+ "/" + file, conn)
```

Comment: We don't have your code so can only guess, but this is complaining about the file not being a directory... which implies that the code is trying to do some sort of directory action on the string. That also suggests that the program input isn't correct. Is it expecting a directory but getting a file name?

Comment: Is this part of a larger python error that showed the failing line of code?

Comment: Yeah, so this program wants to add all csvs in a directory to the database. You are giving it one csv when really it wants a directory holding all of them.

Comment: Go ahead and add the error text you posted briefly in the comments to the question itself. It makes me look less insane and shows future readers what we are talking about.

Comment: I just updated the post to include the portion of code where I am getting the error....hope that helps.

Comment: Change `localFilePath` to `"C:/Users/ajb56/Documents/Programming/"` to import all of the CSVs in that path or get rid of the for loop completely and call `insertRows(localFilePath)` to import just that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `localFilePath` to a file name but then try to use it as a directory name. I don't know your intent, but you should either remove the file name to get all CSVs in the directory

```
import os
localFilePath = "C:/Users/ajb56/Documents/Programming"
for file in os.listdir(localFilePath):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        insertRows(os.path.join(localFilePath, file), conn)
```

or skip the loop completely

```
localFilePath = "C:/Users/ajb56/Documents/Programming/CGS_sales_database.csv"
insertRows(localFilePath conn)
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense.  If there were multiple csv files in the directory then the additional steps would need to take place I am guessing?

Comment: Right. The code is written so that whatever CSVs are put in that directory are added to the database. It would be wise to then rename them to something other than .csv or remove them completely so that the same information isn't added a second time.